# Skype for business iOS SDK: unable to start audioservice

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10, skypedeveloper

I am integrating a Skype's iOS SDK and when I try to start audioservice from conversation helper.

```
do {
    try self.conversationHelper.conversation.audioService.start()
}
catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

I got this error. And audio was neither came through nor went out. (But the videoservice was working fine.)

```
2016-11-12 21:22:00.012 test-skype[669:1aa91fc40] INFO APPLICATION CUcmpAudioModality.cpp:230 CUcmpAudioModality::start(AudioType) called.
2016-11-12 21:22:00.014 test-skype[669:1aa91fc40] INFO APPLICATION CUcmpAudioModality.cpp:259 CUcmpAudioModality::start(AudioType, CUriString) called.
2016-11-12 21:22:00.015 test-skype[669:1aa91fc40] INFO APPLICATION CUcmpAudioVideoModality.cpp:2799 CUcmpAudioModality::queryCapability on StartVoIP returned false because modality state is InConversation
2016-11-12 21:22:00.017 test-skype[669:1aa91fc40] ERROR APPLICATION CUcmpAudioModality.cpp:267 Unable to start audio with error (587726849)
```

How do I fix this? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find a solution. I need to initialize `AVAudioSession` and set category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` first to make it work.

```
let audioSession: AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do{
    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
}
catch let errorForCategory as Error{
    print(errorForCategory.localizedDescription)
}
do{
    try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat)
}
catch let errorForMode as Error {
    print(errorForMode.localizedDescription)
}
```

EDIT: If you plan to use an Airplay on video chat you need to set mode to `AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat` as mention in this document.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html

```
do {
    try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat)
}
catch let errorForMode as Error {
    print(errorForMode.localizedDescription)
}
```